# How to delay a setInterval - Java Script

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

I have an animation in Jquery that I want to repeat with a setInterval every 5 seconds, the problem is that I also want it to wait 5 seconds before starting. I have not find a solution, I thought about something like this but it is not working, it executes immediately:

```
setTimeout(function(){
   bannerInterval = setInterval(function(){
    bannerRotate();
   },5000);
},5000);
bannerRotate();
```

Thanks

Comment: what isn't working about it?

Comment: it executes immediately

Comment: @EddyXP - I don't see the problem? http://jsfiddle.net/d5Uz6/

Comment: if anything, that code should wait 10 seconds before executing the first time, and then execute every 5 seconds after that.

Comment: There must be something else in the code or I'm misunderstanding the question - that piece of code alone should not cause any problems.

Comment: Can't reproduce. The code in the question behaves as expected — http://jsfiddle.net/V7MzC/

Comment: Sorry everybody, my code was correct, I had the function bannerRotate() being executed somewhere else at the same time, I changed my question to show the error

Answer (score 0):

Skip first use by using some variable like:

```
var firstRun = true;
setTimeout(function(){
   bannerInterval = setInterval(function(){
    if (firstRun)
    {
        firstRun = false;
    }else
    {
        bannerRotate();
    }
   },5000);
},5000);
```

Comment: Actually my original code is correct, I was calling bannerRotate() somewhere else that is why it was executing immediately. No need of conditionals.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with **vadim**, your setInterval code will run immediately after the setTimeout is over. The 5000 for your setInterval will not delay the first run of the snippet, rather tells the code how often to repeat it. Simply set the setTimeout timer from 5000 to 10000.

Comment: Actually my original code is correct, I was calling bannerRotate() somewhere else that is why it was executing immediately. SetTimeout waits 5 seconds and then setInterval repeats every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I was executing the function that I was trying to delay outside the setTimeout() function somewhere else in my code.
The code works just as is:

```
setTimeout(function(){
   bannerInterval = setInterval(function(){
    bannerRotate();
   },5000);
},5000);

/* bannerRotate(); WITHOUT THIS PART!!!! */
```

Answer (score -1):

before your code use empty for loop or any looping statement to delay in starting

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {}
```

Comment: That code wouldn't delay anything, a loop like that executes as fast as not having a loop, plus delaying something using is a loop is an extremely bad idea, it is trying to make the computer's processor so busy that it actually stops from executing other commands. Never try such a thing.

Answer (score -2):

use delay() function,try the code given below ,hope this may help you

```
setTimeout(function(){
       bannerInterval = setInterval(function(){
        bannerRotate();
       },5000);
    },5000).delay(5000);
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object 3 has no method 'delay'

Comment: @Atber — Without the delay method the code is identical to the code in the question. If works (which is does) the question is unanswerable and the question should be closed.

Comment: delay is a jquery method, you need to wrap the whole code in jquery, like this: $(...).delay(5000);

Comment: .delay() is a Jquery method for JQuery objects, that would through back an error as @Quentin says, He is also correct, my code had no errors. I changed the question to show the error.